# Is this question ok for electrical engineering?

Tags: support, specific-question

I have an idea for a sports equipment invention "a new product" that a track and field athlete can use to practice and train his sport. The technology involves a laser beam. I'm wondering if my idea is feasible and/or if it has already been done because we think the idea is good. Is there a more appriopriate place to ask about the feasibility of my product idea, or is it ok to ask it at electrical engineering?

Comment: Is it a light-gate that calculates the time between two beam interruptions? Those exist. In fact, many universities create dozens of designs per year as a first or second year student project. Just my $0.02

Comment: @Asmyldof My idea is to use a light beam instead of a bar when doing pole vaulting and high jump. I don't know if it has been done or feasible.

Comment: Sure its feasible. It's called a ***LASER TRIP WIRE*** and has been around for decades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for askng first!

Unless your question is specifically about the design of the electronic circuitry of the product, it sounds like it would be a better fit on the more general [Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I will ask at the general site, the idea is to use a light beam instead of a bar in the sport pole vault and high jump.